# A conjecture about primes: if $a,b$ are coprime and not both odd, is $A(a,b,m)$ finite for some $m$?

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures

Let $p_n$ be the $nth$ prime and define $p_n^{(m)}$ by $p_n^{(1)}=p_n$ and 
$p_n^{(m+1)}=p_{p_n^{(m)}}$:

$p_n^{(2)}=p_{p_n}$, $\;p_n^{(3)}=p_{p_{p_n}}$ and so far...

For some coprime numbers $a,b$, not both odd, do there exist a number $m\in \mathbb Z_+$ such that 
$A(a,b,m)=\{ap_n^{(m)}+b\in\mathbb P|n\in\mathbb Z_+\}$ is finite? $\mathbb P$ is the set of primes.

I have done some tests and there is no sign of finiteness.

> Conjecture:
>   If $a$ and $b$ are coprime and $a+b$ is odd, then
>   $A(a,b,m)$ is infinite for all $m\in\mathbb Z_+$.

One consequence of the conjecture, which I don't expect to be proved, is that any even gap just not only exists but exists infinitely, not only for primes, but also for the case when one of the primes is of the form 
$p_n^{(m)}$ any $m$. So perhaps there is a possibility of counterexamples?

See also [this paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL12/Broughan/broughan16.pdf).

Comment: Ah. Your edit has made everything clearer.

Comment: @MXYMXY. Sorry, I did forget something essential. I have edited.

Comment: I think you must put $$p_n^{(m+1)}=p_{p_n^{(m)}}^{(m)}$$ instead of
$$p_n^{(m+1)}=p_{p_n}^{(m)}$$ Am I wrong?

Comment: For a fixed $m$, the growth rate of $p^{(m)}_n$ is $n (\log n)^m$, which is still a pretty dense sequence.  In particular, the sum of the reciprocal logs diverges, and there are no obvious local restrictions, so heuristically the expected number of primes is infinite and I would be very shocked if there were any signs of finiteness.  However, given that we can't even prove $\{2p_n+1\}$ contains infinitely many primes, this is not approachable by current methods.

Comment: @Piquito, yes something is wrong, but I think it shouldn't be an extra (m) at top. I will edit.

Comment: @Lehs You need to add the restriction that $a$ and $b$ do not have the same parity.  This is clearly false for $a=3, b=5$.

Comment: @ErickWong. You are right. I'm sloppy. Will edit.

Comment: Might be worth providing a literal description of the conjecture (i.e., explain it in words).

Comment: @Lehs Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see how the conjecture implies the existence of all even gaps.  I don't even see how it implies the infinite occurrence of one even gap.  Also, it isn't true: for $m=2$ there are only finitely many gaps of size $2$ or $4$ between primes of the form $p_{p_n}$, and the list grows longer for higher for higher $m$.

Comment: @ErickWong: I changed the former condition $a>1$. If $A(1,2,2)$ is infinite, then  the number of primes of the form $p_{p_n}+2$ would be infinite. Where can I read about this counterexample? Can you formulate an answer?

Comment: @Lehs Oh I see, I misunderstood your comment.  It's true that there are only finitely many gaps between primes of type $p_{p_n}$, but you are only requiring the smaller of the twin primes to be of that form so this fact doesn't contradict your conjecture.